# How to use ng-model and ng-checked together for radio buttons, inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-checked

I am trying to fetch Roles data(JSON) from a url and using ng-repeat to assign it to radio buttons(shows list of roles) and display it in MODAL. Any one option must be selected for the role currently assigned to the user.

When a user changes the selection and clicks ok, selected value should be assigned to an object, which is further passed to a URL to update the role of user.

If i use,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in roleDataList">
        <input type="radio"  ng-model="item"  ng-checked="item.RoleId==assignedRoleId?true:null" name="RoleRadioButton" ng-value="item"  />                   
        <span>{{item.RoleName}}</span>
</div>
```

then it shows the already assigned data as default but i cant access the selected data,

If i use,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in roleDataList">
        <input type="radio"  ng-model="$parent.parentRoleId"  ng-checked="item.RoleId==assignedRoleId?true:null" name="RoleRadioButton" ng-value="item"  />                   
       <span>{{item.RoleName}}</span>
</div>
```

then selected role is available in `$parent.parentRoleId`, but default value is not selected.

Any help where both can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle pretty much what you want i think

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/PQvQ2/)

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<span ng-repeat="category in categories">
  <label class="checkbox" for="{{category.id}}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection.ids[category.id]" name="group" id="{{category.id}}" />
    {{category.name}}
  </label>
</span>
<pre ng-bind="selection.ids | json"></pre>
```

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

$scope.selection = {
    ids: {"50d5ad": true}
};

$scope.categories = [ { "name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } , {"name": "General", "id": "678ffr" } ];
```

}

Comment: 1) My input type is radio.
2) roleDataList wil have values like <RolesModel><RoleCreatedBy>1</RoleCreatedBy><RoleCreatedDate>2015-06-12T14:17:03.527</RoleCreatedDate><RoleCreatedUserName i:nil="true"/><RoleDescription>Associate of the company</RoleDescription><RoleId>1</RoleId><RoleName>Associate</RoleName></RolesModel>

3) i want when my Modal loads, "Associate" should be selected, if RoleId matches with the assignedID and if user changes its role, new role id should be received at controller, so i can pass it to another URL.

Comment: I am not really sure what your goal is can u provide a fiddle / codepen which helps me clarify.